# Ion Implantation

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I have a very basic question regarding ion plantation: when Silicon is doped with Boron, for example, it is doped by Boron **atoms** (3 valent electrons). When it is doped with phosphorus, for example, it is also doped by phosphorus **atoms** (5 valent electrons), so how come the implantation is of **ions**?
Thank you very mutch

Comment: well, if you are shooting neutral atoms, it would be a bit difficult to accelerate them. With ions, you can accelerate them and also collimate them into a beam using electro-optics.

Comment: @IamAStudent - Although modern high current implant systems in industry actually do some level of charge neutralization (post-accel) to reduce space charge effects on the beam shape at the wafer. Fun fact: William Shockley (yes, that Shockley) patented (US #2,787,564) ion implantation for semiconductor device manufacturing in 1957 since he recognized the utility in precise dose definition it allowed.

Comment: @JonCuster, interesting. So how is the neutralization carried out?

Comment: @IamAStudent - you inject an electron beam into the stream. Fairly easy to do with a very small magnetic field (which does not significantly impact the ions) since the electrons are much lighter than the ions (even protons).

Comment: As a further reason why implantation, different ion energies allow the dopants to be placed at different depths (well, their peak concentration). Thus, you can do deep-well implants at a few MeV, while all the device implants (source/gate/drain) are in the keV range.

Comment: Thank you. So from what I understand, in ion plantation the Silicon is implanted with, for example B3+ or P3- ?

Comment: @Shany - no, it would be just (usually) a simple +1 ion (note that a 3- charge ion is intrinsically unstable and will rapidly eject an electron). I'll work on an answer...

Answer (score 1):

The reasons to use ion implantation to introduce dopants into semiconductors (or specific impurities into, say, optically active thin films) are at least threefold. All were envisioned quite early in transistor technology by William Shockley (co-inventor of the transistor) in a 1954 patent application, granted in [1957](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2787564A/en). The big three reasons are:

1. Get one specific impurity, and only one: Once you have made ions, you can accelerate them and then use a magnetic field to select a specific charge:mass ratio to send down the beamline to your devices. From a practical perspective, this allows you to pick one element (and one isotope) to put into your material. So, using a phosphine gas as the feed for an ion source, you are accelerating phosphorous and hydrogen ions out of the ion source. You use a magnet to pick only the phosphorous. Phosphorous only has one isotope, so no further selection is necessary. Boron, however, has two isotopes, and you'd get one (usually the isotope with the highest natural occurrence, but there may be other reasons to select a specific isotope).
2. Place the impurity at just the right depth: semiconductor devices are in three dimensions, and often you want one doping region underneath another. A given ion at a given implant energy will have a resulting impurity profile in the substrate. Higher incident energy means it goes further in, lighter ions will go further than heavier ions at the same energy. This profile can be thought of to first order as a gaussian centered on a specific depth with a width. There are also higher fidelity models with, e.g., skew and kurtosis. Now, this as-implanted distribution will change with the anneal sequence needed to get the implanted dopants on to lattice sites, but still you get to control the depth. This is most obvious in technologies that had a so-called deep-well implant, often several microns deep, well below the transistors. In a classic surface in-diffusion process from the 1960's this would be essentially impossible since the surface concentration of the well doping would be insanely high.
3. You also want a specific amount of the dopant. Note that as device dimensions have shrunk, the amount (and allowed variation of the amount) have shrunk as well, so a high degree of control of the amount of dopant implanted is required. With ions this is (pretty) easy - you scan the ion beam across an aperture, with the wafer behind it. Overscan to make the beam go fully off the aperture. Then, the number of ions per square area that go into the device is just the charge collected on the wafer divided by the area of the implant on the wafer.

So, you use ion implantation to get the right amount of the right impurity in the right place.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I see one of the difference between doping with diffusion and doping with ion plantation is that in diffusion the Silicon is doped by atoms (like As, B, P) and in ion plantation the Silicon is doped by ions (like As+, B+, P- ). Did I get it right? Thanks again

Comment: I just read that it's not P- but rather a P+ . So now I don't get it, because P+ has 4 valence electrons that can make 4 covalent bonding with the other Si atoms around it, and there is no fifth free electron to be a charge carrier, unlike a P atom, so it seems to me that doping with P+ is missing the point of having an extra electron to be the charge carrier. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The ion is just a way to get the dopant into the silicon in the first place. Once there, by either diffusion or implantation, it is in the lattice and there is no net charge about (during implantation the wafer has to be grounded to prevent charge build up, but that is the only concern with what charge the ion has). An ion implanted P or a diffused P will happily end up on a lattice site and be an electron donor.

Comment: @Shany - if you believe this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark. Although waiting a bit longer might be considered good form, to see if another, better answer comes along.